# Determining if a child div has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with some code that allows content editors to add content. I've found a few instances where there is a div that has children (like `h5` or `p`) but no text. The div is taking up space and I would like to remove all of the divs that have no actual text in it.

The only thing I've found is the `:empty` css selector, but that checks for children, not text.

```js
$('.col-lg-4:empty').remove();
```

```css
.col-lg-4 {
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h5 class="headline1">Test Title</h5>
    <p class="p2"></p>
    <p>This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.</p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h5 class="subtitle1"></h5>
    <p class="p2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <p class="p2 last-column"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

This is some real content from my site that editors have added. As you can see, I have unnecessary divs with no content (the `.col-lg-4` ones) that I would like to get rid of. With the `:empty`, it removes the last one that has no children. But what would be the best way to remove the ones that have children that have no content?

Comment: Select them, loop over, check the text length, hide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want to do?

I can't think of an easier way to do it!
Check the snippet:

```js
$('.col-lg-4').each(function() {
  if (!this.innerText)  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.col-lg-4 {
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h5 class="headline1">Test Title</h5>
    <p class="p2"></p>
    <p>This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.This is some filler text that I have added for testing purposes.</p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h5 class="subtitle1"></h5>
    <p class="p2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <p class="p2 last-column"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

I used `innerText` to get rid of all the html tags.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is definitely a very efficient way, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over them, check for empty children, remove:

```js
$('.col-lg-4').each(function () {
  if ($(this).children().text() == '') $(this).remove();
});
```

Without jQuery:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.col-lg-4'))
  .filter(i => !i.innerText)
  .forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
```